# distance to polygon boundary

Tags: qgis

i have a layer of points, and a vector layer of county boundaries for the UK. I would like to be able to find the nearest county boundary to any given point and the distance using QGIS. any ideas?

I've installed processing, and trying to use those tools -- but no luck so far. I tried converting the polygon to nodes, but the nodes are spaced too widely for this to be accurate.

Answer (score 4):

first convert your polygons to lines
[How can I transform a polygon to a linestring in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15819/how-can-i-transform-a-polygon-to-a-linestring-in-qgis)

then get the distance between your points and the lines
[Join attributes of point and line layer by location (closest distance) in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/join-attributes-of-point-and-line-layer-by-location-closest-distance-in-qgis)