# need to populate attribute table

Tags: attribute-table

I have two shapefiles, one polygon one points.  The points represent specific field sampling locations.  The polygons represent land divisions.  The land divisions have a unique 16 digit identifier.  The plots have numbers unique to each polygon.  Ie:  polygon 0401010011190084 has plots 1-4.  I need to create a field in the plots shapefile that will be populated with the polygon number in which it lies.  Typing them in by hand sucks.  I need to populate this field in order to get the plots to load correctly into a database.  How can do this easily?    The plots shapefile needs to remain as points only.

Comment: What software are you using? and if ArcGis what license level?

Comment: Please **edit** your question to provide the information requested above.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a spatial join between the two layers.  This joins the two layers based on a spatial rule you can define.
[For ArcMap](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000)
[For QGIS](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_spatial.php)

Comment: That's a fine answer. Without knowing the software it's hard to give instructions - but at least the Op can download QGIS if they don't already have it. One other handy tip when joining *points* to any geometry type is *Near* (advanced license only) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001q000000 and as described http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/join-attributes-of-point-and-line-layer-by-location-closest-distance-in-qgis then attribute join.